# Parallel evaluate mathematica notebook

Tags: parallelization

I have several mathematical notebooks and want to evaluate them by NotebookEvaluate[], since there are irrelevant to each other, so I think I can evaluate them parallelly. However, it seems difficult to achieve.
It seems the notebooks are evaluated on different Kernels (ignore the warning about the front end)
[image]

but there's only one Kernel is active in Windows Task Manager actually
[image]

I also try to use different function to parallelize the evaluation, it seems the evaluation is on the different Kernels, but in Windows Task Manager, there still only one Kernek is activity.

[image]

I can write the notebook as a very long function, and parallel evaluate them. But if I insist to keep them as notebook (it has some convenience), how can I parallel evaluate them.